# MediaScanner runs on an sdcard, after the sdcard was ejected?

Tags: android, sd-card

The below code shows me that the MediaScanner has started *on the sdcard, after it ejects* why? and what is happening?

```
if(intent.getDataString().equals("file:///mnt/extsd"))
        {
            if(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED.equals(intent.getAction()))
            {
                //Media scanner is started
            }
            else if(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED.equals(intent.getAction()))
            {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Probably this question will be helpfull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604220/cant-create-folder-in-extsd-card) Its about `/mnt/extsd` and how to use SD card properly (means `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`). Also you have to check the SD card state. I mean like:

```
boolean isExternalStorageWriteable = false, isExternalStorageReadable = false;
// Check SD Card for Read/Write
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    isExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    isExternalStorageReadable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    isExternalStorageReadable = true;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but
    // all we need
    // to know is we can neither read nor write
}
```

Comment: Thing is, /mnt/sdcard IS the output of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() but that link is helpful nonetheless

Comment: actually you have to check the SD card state also. I mean like in code below.